# Mapstruct extending multiple interfaces containing method with the same signature

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I use 2 libraries in my project which require mappers with the different interfaces:

```
public interface FirstLibraryMapper<T, M> {

    M mapToDto(T domain);

    List<M> mapToDto(List<T> domains);

}

public interface SecondLibraryMapper<T, M> {

    M mapToDto(T domain);

}
```

I want to create a single mapper bean using mapstruct that will be injected in libraries components by interface because both interfaces have a method with exact signature:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper extends FirstLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto>, SecondLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto> {

}
```

When I try to compile, I get this error:

```
Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element to MyDto: MyDto mapToDto(MyDomain arg0), MyDto mapToDto(MyDomain arg0).
```

I was able to bypass this issue by using @Named and @IterableMapping but it feels wrong and clunky. Why can't mapstruct processor ignore the second method if it has an exact signature as the first one? Should I rise an issue on their github page? Or am I wrong in that case?

Comment: Your Mapper is mapping the same objects with the same signitature? How would java know to distringuish them?

Comment: `Why can't mapstruct processor ignore`. But why it should ignore? The behaviour of both methods might be different despite the same signature. How would `MapStruct` choose what exactly do you want?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Correct me if i am wrong, but how can methods behaviour differ if in the impl class there will be only one method that is accessible from both interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by overriding method in result mapper which is still a bit clunky but seems to do the trick.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper extends FirstLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto>, SecondLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto> {

    @Override
    MyDto mapToDto(MyDomain domain);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider combining both mappers under some sort of Facade pattern?

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyFirstMapper extends FirstLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto> {
}

@Mapper
public interface MySecondMapper extends SecondLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto> {
}

@Service
public class MyMapperFacade extends FirstLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto>, SecondLibraryMapper<MyDomain, MyDto> {

    @Autowired
    private MyFirstMapper firstMapper;

    @Autowired
    private MySecondMapper secondMapper;

    @Override
    public MyDto mapToDto(MyDomain domain) {
        return firstMapper.mapToDto(domain); // always delegate to FirstLibraryMapper
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i did but that would require to duplicate mappings, and i would like to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

You could have one mapper. You shouldn't specify types of mapping:

```
@Mapper
public interface Mapper {

    Dto1 mapToDto1(Domain1 domain1);

    List<Dto1> mapToDto1(List<Domain1> domains1);

    Dto2 mapToDto2(Domain2 domain2);

}
```

Comment: The thing is - FirstLibraryMapper and SecondLibraryMapper are interfaces of two different libraries that should not be coupled with one another. It just so happens that i use them both in the same component.

Comment: @PashchenkoDenis I think MapStruct hasn't this functionality. You should raise a ticket to them